# Emacs Inferior Python shell shows the send message with each python-shell-send-region command

Tags: python, macos, emacs, python.el, comint-mode

I am using the Python inferior shell on OS X (El Capitan) and every time I send a piece of code to the Python process (using `C-c C-r` which is bound to `python-shell-send-region`) I get a message like this in the Python shell:

```
>>> import codecs, os;
    __pyfile = codecs.open('''/var/folders/6j/g9hcs1s17g1dgxr3p_m04rq80000gn/T/py5013kfY''', encoding='''utf-8''');
    __code = __pyfile.read().encode('''utf-8''');
    __pyfile.close();
    os.remove('''/var/folders/6j/g9hcs1s17g1dgxr3p_m04rq80000gn/T/py5013kfY''');
    exec(compile(__code, '''/Users/user/Desktop/sample.py''', 'exec'));
```

I would like to not have this message shown with each invocation of the command. The same version of Emacs on Linux (together with python.el file) does not have this problem. The template of the message is defined in `python-shell-send-file` function (in `python.el` file), which in itself is puzzling as I cannot see how this function is called when I invoke `python-shell-send-region`. For the first run I invoke the Python interpreter (version 2.7.10) with the following command

```
/usr/bin/python -i
```

but it also behaves the same with other python interpreters (installed via brew). I am using Emacs 24.5.1 (again installed via brew). The only python-mode specific configuration I use in `.emacs` are related to the tab width:

```lisp
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
        (setq tab-width 2)
        (setq python-indent 2)))
```

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

**Edit and a possible solution**:

(I found this https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/1307):

```
$ easy_install-3.6 gnureadline
$ cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
$ mv readline.cpython-36m-darwin.so readline.cpython-36m-darwin.so.bak
```

If you get an error while installing gnureadline, `fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found`, try `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: I have found a workaround for this annoyance. `ipython` seems to not have the same issue for me. You can set the `python-shell-interpreter` to ipython (something like this in your `.emacs`): `(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython2")`

Comment: That solution(issues/1307) works for me either with slight changes.  
`easy_install-3.6 => pip3 install`  
`3.6 => 3.7`  
`36m => 37m`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ source ./your/venv/activate
$ pip install pyreadline
```

Should work automatically with [Python](https://pythonhosted.org/pyreadline/usage.html#pyreadline-with-ipython). I experienced a similar issue on Windows 10 earlier this year, installing [pyreadline](https://pypi.org/project/pyreadline/) as a dev dependency resolved it.